# what's the difference between `speed` and `response speed` on charlse?

Tags: proxy

[image: Image of proxy stats]

Charlse proxy software, I don't know the difference between speed and response speed, anyone can answer it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone in the future (since I was just struggling with this) it is the Total size in kiloBytes (the request + the response) divided by the duration (convert to seconds)